# create query in DB without model. Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

pls bare with me im awful at explaining.

I have made a linking table for **user** and **roles**. Its called **user_role**, the controller is called **UserRoleController**. Someone told me that a linking table isn't supposed to have a model, so can someone explain me how i can do a query then? It doesnt' recognize UserRole::create because i haven't put a "use App\Models\UserRole" inside it obviously.

.

***So basically my quistion is:***

- I want to do ***UserRole::create($validated);*** inside the UserRole controller. So how do i exactly connect **user_role** DB to its controller without the model?

This is my **UserRoleController**, i removed some code thats unnecessary to see thats why i have so much *"**use**":

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRoleStoreRequest;
use App\Models\Roles;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\UserRole;

class UserRoleController extends Controller
{

    public function store(UserRoleStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        UserRole::create($validated);
        return redirect('/user-role');
    }
}
```

Comment: you should read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::table('user_role')->insert($validated);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: this does not work and is not smart. It doesn't use Eloquent if u use that.
Correct way is:

$validated = $request->validated();
$user = User::find($validated['user_id']);
$user->roles()->attach([$validated['role_id']]);

Answer (score 1):

Ok i fixed it. im not supposed to create a new query.

```
 $validated = $request->validated();
    $user = User::find($validated['user_id']);
    $user->roles()->attach([$validated['role_id']]);
```